# Disable A button when my Queue is = 0 Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I disable this button When my Queue is zero or null?

Here is my view Button:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new AjaxOptions
                            {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "current",
                            LoadingElementId = "loading",
                            OnBegin = "ClearResults",
                            }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1" })
```

here is the  controller:

```
public ActionResult BtnNext()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();
    TempData["QueueItem"] = first;
    return PartialView("_queuenumber");
}
```

Comment: `if (_queuenumber == 0) Button.Visible = false;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your cshtml as below

```
<style>
    .disabled {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
    }
</style>

@{
    string cssClass = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim";
    if (MyQueue.todayQueue == null || MyQueue.todayQueue.length == 0)
    {
        cssClass += " disabled";
    }
}

@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new AjaxOptions
                            {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "current",
                            LoadingElementId = "loading",
                            OnBegin = "ClearResults",
                            }, new { @class = @cssClass, @id = "Link1" })
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on 
if (MyQueue.todayQueue == null || MyQueue.todayQueue.length == 0)
Error message: The name 'MyQueue' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Did you import namespace of MyQueue in cshtml?

Comment: yes I did , @model IEnumerable<Rosh.QueueMe.Web.Models.MyQueue>, it's weird